# Is there any free stacking program that stack images which are not aligned?

Tags: photography, software

I liked to photo deep-sky-objects and planets with my camera Canon sx130. But I have never stacked images because they were too much apart. I was looking for some free astronomy stacking program for stacking photos that aren't perfectly aligned, like doing the mosaics, but I found just Deep Sky Stacker. It does not stack images that aren't aligned and I have some troubles with it.

For examples, I want to stack this image:

¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸
¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸×¸
¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸
¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸

and this image:

¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸
¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸
¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸
¸×¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸
¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸¸

("¸" is the dark sky and "×" is a planet.)

Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to align the planet or the background ?  Big difference.

Comment: Both of them. For example, I want to stack upper images with × Jupiter and ¸ star background. I want to align the star background and Jupiter, too.